# Incorrect Syntax in Nested Loop

Tags: powershell

I have a power-shell script to drop databases that have no connections in the last 30 days. I have coded the script as below:

```bsh
$SQLInstances = "sql2016", "sql2014", "sql2012"

$SQLQuery = "exec usp_ConnectionsCount"

foreach ($sqLInstance in $SQLInstances) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqLInstance -Database "master" -Query $SQLQuery
}

Write-Output "Any database that has not been used in the last 30 days will be dropped"
Write-Output "Here is a list of SQL Instances being monitored:" $SQLInstances

$DBQuery =  "SELECT Name as DatabaseName FROM [SQLConnections] WHERE number_of_connections = 0 AND DATEDIFF(day,  timestamp, GetDate()) > 30"

$DropDb = "IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = '$UnusedDB') DROP DATABASE $UnusedDB"

foreach ($sqLInstance in $SQLInstances) {
    $Databases = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqLInstance -Database "master" -Query $DBQuery

    Write-Output "List of Databases to be dropped"
    $Databases

    foreach ($UnusedDB in $Databases) {
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqLInstance -Database "master" -Query $DropDb
    }
}
```

My code looks cool to me but when I run it, it says

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Incorrect syntax near 'DATABASE'.

I can't figure out where the problem is. Additionally the code for creating SQLConnections table is:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SQLConnections](
 [server] [nvarchar](130) NOT NULL,
 [name] [nvarchar](130) NOT NULL,
 [number_of_connections] [int] NOT NULL,
 [timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And the code for the `usp_ConnectionsCount` is as follows:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ConnectionsCount 
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [SQLConnections]
  SELECT @@ServerName AS server
 ,NAME AS dbname
 ,COUNT(STATUS) AS number_of_connections
 ,GETDATE() AS timestamp
FROM sys.databases sd
LEFT JOIN master.dbo.sysprocesses sp ON sd.database_id = sp.dbid
WHERE database_id NOT BETWEEN 1
  AND 4
GROUP BY NAME
END
```

Can someone tell me where the incorrect syntax is coming from? I have been looking at this for hours and cant figure out?

Comment: I think the error has something to do with your database names. Have a look at: `... DROP DATABASE $UnusedDB"`. Have you tried wrapping $UnusedDB with [ ] ?

Comment: @Marc If I wrap that variable with [], it doesn't work. I get this error: Invoke-Sqlcmd : An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a
name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias
to a valid name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have abandoned the idea of letting powershell do most of the work. I have managed to use SQL code to do most of the work:

$SQLInstances = "sql2016", "sql2014", "sql2012"

```
Write-Output "Any database that has not been used in the last 30 days will be dropped"
Write-Output "Here is a list of SQL Instances being monitored:" $SQLInstances
$DropDb = " --Exec stored procedure to gather information regarding DB connections
            EXEC usp_fpmConnectionsCount

            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempSQLConnections1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempSQLConnections

            SELECT Distinct(fund.name)
            INTO #TempSQLConnections 
            FROM FundSQLConnections AS fund
            INNER JOIN
            sys.databases as sdb
            on fund.name = sdb.name
            WHERE number_of_connections = 0 AND DATEDIFF(day,  timestamp, GetDate()) > 30 

            GO
            DECLARE @dbnames nvarchar(max)
            DECLARE @statement nvarchar(max)
            SET @dbnames = ''
            SET @statement = ''
            SELECT @dbnames = @dbnames + ',[' + name + ']' from #TempSQLConnections 

            IF len(@dbnames) = 0
                begin
                print 'no databases to drop'
                end
            ELSE
                begin
                set @statement = 'drop database ' + substring(@dbnames, 2, len(@dbnames))
                print @statement
                exec sp_executesql @statement
                print @dbnames + 'Has been dropped'
                end

            DROP TABLE #TempSQLConnections "

    foreach($sqLInstance in $SQLInstances) {

        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqLInstance -Database "master" -Query $DropDb

    }
```

Works like a Hammer!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You've a string quoting problem in :

```
$DropDb = "IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = '$UnusedDB') DROP DATABASE $UnusedDB"
```

Powershell won't replace variables in a single quoted string, there Powershell won't replace `$UnusedDB` and keeps it as text in the string.

You can change it to:

```
$DropDb = "IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = `"$UnusedDB`") DROP DATABASE $UnusedDB"
```

You can find more about quoting rules [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6).

You can also try formatting the string via the `-f` operator, documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6).

Hope that helps.